# Error When using imagettftext() with '&' in text

Tags: php, html-entities, imagettftext

I am using below code to write text and change color,size,font and add it on image.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);
$color1 = imagecolorallocate($im, $rgb1[0], $rgb1[1], $rgb1[2]);

$text = 'Testing...'; // Working fine
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $color1 , "arial.ttf", $text);

$newtext = 'Testing & Demo'; // Not Working
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $color1 , "arial.ttf", $newtext);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

**Wrong Output:**

```
test &amp; Demo
```

[image]

**Correct output:**

```
test & Demo
```

I have tried `htmlentities(),trim(),urlencode()` but didnt get desire output.

Please help me to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried your solution... same output coming. Didnt worked.

Comment: Simply don't use `htmlentities()`. You're not writing to an HTML document so there's no need to HTML encode.

Comment: I have tried it not used and without use of htmlentities() also not worked. Please dnt do it minus vote. @Phil

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can see (apart from using `htmlentities()` in an image) is that you're actually passing a string for the colour instead of an integer. This works just fine for me...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 60);
$colour = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$font = '/path/to/font.ttf';

$text = 'Testing...';
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $colour, $font, $text);

$newtext = 'Testing & Demo';
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 40, $colour, $font, $newtext);

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

[image]

Comment: Check my edited code. I have used that in my project. But for example I forgot to add it here in question. I have added image and edited question with correct color what i got.

Comment: @RuchishParikh You still appear to be using `htmlentities()`. Don't do that.

Comment: sorry i forgot to remove from code. I have tried without it but wont work I have applied so many things. Thanks for your support. @Phil